# Why Does JQuery Append Reverse The Order of My Statement ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm news to JS.  I am using this Ajax call. It works fine, except that for some reason the **"input type-"checkbox"** always appears first on the screen, when in fact I want it second to the **product_name**.  I have tried swapping it the other way around, and the checkbox always come first.

What can I do to get the product_name first, then the checkbox ?

```
 $.ajax({                                                                        // if this is a CREATE QUOTE, we use the product_id to grab the PRICE using AJAX //
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:"json",
        url: 'category_prices/' + value,
        success: function (categories) {
         $cat_products.empty();
         $.each(categories,function(i, product){
         $cat_products.append('<p col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-md-offset-0>' +product.product_name+ '<input type="checkbox" class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-md-offset-2" value="cat_id">  </p>') 
            });

        }
    });
```

HTML

```
 <div class="cat_products"></div>
```

Comment: `$cat_products.append('<p col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-md-offset-0><span>' +product.product_name+ '</span><input type="checkbox" class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-md-offset-2" value="cat_id"> </p>');`

Comment: try recreating your problem in a jsFiddle or a code snippet here in SO so we dont have to guess what your output is and what the problem might be

Comment: Should be using a label

Comment: I thought it might be an easy thing to guess. Sorry. 
I would put it into Fiddle except that 'product' is generated by an Ajax /  DB and the whole event is fired by a change in the category select drop down.

Comment: @epascarello  Thank you that fixed it !!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using bootstrap 3. In that case, change

```
      $cat_products.append('<p col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-md-offset-0>' +product.product_name+ '<input type="checkbox" class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-md-offset-2" value="cat_id">  </p>')
```

to

```
     $cat_products.append('<p class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-md-offset-0">' +product.product_name+ '<input type="checkbox" class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-md-offset-2" value="cat_id">  </p>')
```

Notice `class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-md-offset-0"` with the <p> tag you are appending. The reason this is happening is because Bootstrap adds `float:left` property to classes `col-sm-2 col-md-2`. Also, note that you should avoid using these classes with the <p> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your p tag is missing class="" wrapped around the col-sm2- etc

Comment: Thank you for that - it did not fix the problem though.